# How many ways can we implement Drag & Drop functionality using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop, webdriver

How many ways can we implement Drag & Drop functionality using Selenium and Java?

Code attempt:

```
Thread.sleep(3000);
WebElement FROM = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='item-container flex-container-horizontal'])[1]"));
Thread.sleep(3000);
WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Product Quality?']"));
Thread.sleep(3000);
Actions act=new Actions(driver);
act.dragAndDrop(FROM, to).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Drag and Drop functionality can be implemented in multiple ways as follows:

- Using `dragAndDrop()`:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/droppable/");
  driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='demo-frame']")));
  WebElement from = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("draggable")));
  WebElement to = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("droppable")));
  new Actions(driver).dragAndDrop(from, to).build().perform();
  ```
- Chaining `clickAndHold()` and `moveToElement()`:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/droppable/");
  driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='demo-frame']")));
  WebElement drag = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("draggable")));
  WebElement drop = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("droppable")));
  new Actions(driver).clickAndHold(from).moveToElement(to).release(from).build().perform();
  ```
- Video demonstration:

[image: dragdrop]